# How to set a max/limit on how much a movieclip can be moved by x and y?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm making a Create-a-Character.One of the features is being able to adjust a facial feature’s placement.E.g. can move the nose up or down
(Through arrow buttons, example: 1 click on up button, move nose up by a little bit.)

But obviously I don't want the eyes or nose or lips floating outside the face or a nose ending up on a forehead that would be strange lol.

So how do I code so that the user can only move a movieclip a set amount of times in the chosen direction?

Comment: There is a limiting rectangle if you use `startDrag()`, otherwise you need to attach constraints to an object manually and check them whenever it gets moved.

Comment: You can subclass **MovieClip** and override setters for **x** and **y**. Not sure if that works with **startDrag(...)** but you can try and figure it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use just arrow buttons to move objects, it is very easy. Once a button is clicked, check object's position and move it if needed. Basic example:

```
// if arrow up clicked
if (nose.y > 100)
{nose.y -= 2}

// if down arrow clicked
if (nose.y < 140)
{nose.y += 2}
```

It's same for x axis and obviously, numbers 100 and 140 can be anything you want. It means, move objects just between these points.

Answer (score 0):

User 987 answer is correct, however if your button moves the object at a faster pace say +-5, setting +-2 to the offset might not put it back in the boundary. It will correct itself by +-2 every frame there after, not accounting for if the user continues to hold down the button to try and exceed the boundary further. The nose will continue to glide further away.

The better way to implement this is to immediately set the nose back to the edge of the boundary.

```
if (nose.y > 140) {
  nose.y = 140;
}
```